# Completion of polynomial space with max norm

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let's start with space of finite polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$. Weierstrass theorem says it's dense in $C[0;1]$ by norm $\|P(t)\|=\max|P(t)|, t \in [0,1]$. So the completion of this space is $C[0,1]$.

But what if norm $\|P(t)\|=\max|P(t)| + \max|P'(t)|$? It seems like the completion should be $C^1[0,1]$. But i don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I proved it.

$f \in C^1[0;1]$, so $f' \in C[0;1]$

By Weierstrass theorem $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there is polynomial $Q(x)$ such that

$|Q(x)-f'(x)|<\epsilon / 2\ \ \forall x\in [0;1] $

Obviously there is $P(x): P'(x) = Q(x), P(0) = f(0)$.

$P(x) - P(0) = \int\limits_0^x Q(\xi) d \xi$

$f(x) - f(0) = \int\limits_0^x f'(\xi) d \xi$

So

$P(x) - f(x) = \int\limits_0^x (Q(\xi) - f'(x)) d \xi$

$|P(x) - f(x)| \le \int\limits_0^x |Q(\xi) - f'(x)| d \xi \le \int\limits_0^1 |Q(\xi) - f'(x)| d \xi < \epsilon / 2$

So

$\max|P(x)-f(x)| + \max|P'(x)-f'(x)|<\epsilon$

Polynomials are dense in $C^1[0;1]$ and therefore completion of polynomial space with such norm is $C^1[0;1]$.